# Ruby comparing biggest potential number

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, comparison

Quick one. i have an array [92,901] i want to arrange these so that if they were compacted together they would generate the biggest potential number. in this case it would be 92 then 901 to make 92901. These numbers could be huge as well and there could be many integers in the array.

I was going to split each number into an array and then compare each digit to the corresponding opposing array place. i feel that there would be a better ruby way of doing this.

Comment: is there always 2 numbers?

Comment: there can be quite a few numbers. [1,2,99,901] example would be 99 then 901 then 2 then 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ar = [1,2,99,901] 
p ar.map(&:to_s).sort.reverse.join.to_i   # => 9990121

p ar.sort_by(&:to_s).reverse # => [99, 901, 2, 1]
```

This creates an array of strings,which are sorted alphabetically.This sorting is from low to high - the opposite is needed, so the sorted array is reversed.

Comment: That works, and is mind bending at the same time! its going to take me a while to see how that works

Comment: ok so when a integer is converted to a string it then has an alphabetical reference. and the reference of 9 would in this case be lower than 1, and then we reverse it and alphabetically 99 would be higher than 901?

Comment: `map(&:to_s)` creates an array of strings (`ar` stays what it is, an array of integers). These strings are sorted low to high, a to z, 0 to 9. The resulting array is reversed, so it is now 9 to 0.